# Using level 2 cache in small java ee aplication

Tags: jakarta-ee, caching

I'm working on an inventory application that will be used in intranet by using java ee 6 from about 20 users.
do i really need 2nd level caching in this situation?

Comment: Are you referring to the second level cache typically offered by JPA implementations?

Comment: Shared (L2) Entity Cache

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really enough information to answer this question.  But anytime you can improve the performance of something do so.  Your application may grow and you will need that caching.  Further the use of caching is greatly dependent on realizing the tradeoffs of space verse time.  More space = less time and the inverse of this is equally true.   Consider the following scenario:

Without caching each query on the system takes 1 second.  With caching each query takes .5 seconds but the time to build / refresh the cache is 20 minutes

At a certain point the cache is useless.  Math to follow.  Assuming caches must be rebuilt every hour to have a performance gain the number of queries per hour must exceed  80 queries per second to break even.

```
20 minutes for the cache (60*20)  
.5 seconds per query (2 per second)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a second level cache to speed up certain JPA operations can give your application an interesting performance boost, and in the cases I know of it's an almost zero-effort configuration item.  However, it can introduce a couple of very annoying side effects:

- if your application is loaded as several deployables (ear's, war's) typically each of these deployed application will have its own second level cache.  The result is that an update done in one application will not be reflected immediately in the other applications, they'll continue to use their cached, but now stale copies of the data.
- same problem if your application is not entirely built using JPA, the same staleness will happen.

That's why on data that are frequently modified you should not use second level caching.

Comment: my app loaded as a single war and doesn't frequently modified with a small number of user and a not a lot of transactions

Comment: okay, in that case parts or most of the data could benefit from second level caching.  Just keep the potential risks in mind.